# Spring Entity inheritance, getting null from repository when using findOne

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

In spring, JPA, i want to extend my User model into More more User types.
And i like it to be in a single table.

i believe i did my example right, but some how i am getting `null` for the `findOne` method

can you help my please, i can't figure out what is wrong

here is my code (I have more users types, but the basic is not working):

**User:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="user_type")
public abstract class User {
    public LicenseType license = LicenseType.FREE;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    public String username;
    public String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Country country;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public UserPhoto profilePhoto;
    .... 
    ....
}
```

**UserBasic**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("UserBasic")
public class UserBasic extends User {

}
```

**UserRepository**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface UserRepository<T extends User> extends Repository<T, Long>{
    T findOne(Long id);
    T findByFacebookId(Long facebookId);
}
```

**UserBasicRepository**

```
public interface UserBasicRepository extends UserRepository<UserBasic>{
    @Modifying
    @Query(value="UPDATE User SET someField = now() WHERE id = ?1", nativeQuery= true)
    long updateSomeField(Long userId);
}
```

**UserService**

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserBasicRepository userBasicRepository;

    @Override
    public User findOne(Long userId) {

        /**
         *
         *  THIS WILL RETURN NULL
         *  vv
         *
         */

        return userBasicRepository.findOne(userId);
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

---

### QUESTION UPDATE

now after the comment, i printed the query and i think i see the problem

```
and userbasic0_.user_type='UserBasic'
```

i just wanted inheritance, didn't ask for extra comment. how can i remove this condition.

```
Hibernate: 
select
    userbasic0_.id as id2_8_0_,
    userbasic0_.password as passwor12_8_0_,
    userbasic0_.username as usernam15_8_0_,
    .....
from
    User userbasic0_ 
where
    userbasic0_.id=? 
    and userbasic0_.user_type='UserBasic'
```

Comment: How did you save the user? What does the database contain? Which ID are you passing. Because the most obvious explanation is that this user just doesn't exist.

Comment: you comment did help, and show where the problem is. updating the question

Comment: Well, you're asking for a UserBasic. How could hibernate know if a row is a UserBasic, a UserFancy, a UserWithSuperPowers if it doesn't use the discriminator? That's what it's for.

Comment: i care for UserBasic to SELECT only X columns and for UserWithSuperPowers  to SELECT with all columns.  And sometimes i want UserBasic for ID=100 and sometimes i want to UPDATE UserWithSuperPowers that have ID = 100.  I Just want the select to get less columns in the rest of the time that is not UserWithSuperPowers

Comment: That's not what entity inheritance is for. Entity inheritance allows storing storing a Dog (ID=1) and a Cat (ID=2) in the database, then finding an Animal by ID=1, and getting back the Dog, and finding an Animal by ID=2, and getting back the Cat. What you're looking for is lazy loading of properties, or queries selecting only a few properties rather than all of them, or JPA fetch groups. What you're trying to do is store a Dog, and hope to get it back as a Cat. That is, by design, not possible. Because a Cat is not a Dog.

Comment: thanks you for the answer.  all my properties are lazy loading, and when i try to select specific fields, jpa complaining about missing columns to select... i am new to this situation. (i will look for JPA fetch groups)

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for your comment, after reading more about this topic,  i have a bit of better understanding of the problem. and i have another question, Do you think that using "Inheritance"  and "DiscriminatorFormula" (to avoid the extra column, or maybe always return true somehow, so no extra query is needed, just get what i ask for) will be a good solution ?, or a good idea ?. thank you for you help